# Algorithm for grouping sequential strings

Tags: php, algorithm, sequence

I'm really having a hard time devising an algorithm to solve the following problem :

I will be accepting an array of inputs like below :

```
$input = array('100', '101', '102', '110', '111', '112');
```

and the output should be a string containing :

```
"100-102, 110-112".
```

Basically what I need to do is to **group numbers in sequence,** like **100 to 102** and form them in a string **"100-102"** since all numbers form a sequence. But since the value **110 is not next to 102**, values **110 to 112 should be grouped and the string "110-112" will be formed.**

Input is **not limited to numbers however,** they are strings. So I will be expecting inputs like:

```
$input = array('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'GX1', 'GX2', 'Z-3');
```

Following the same pattern, the output should be:

```
"N1-N3, GX1-GX3, Z-3"
```

My pseudo-code (i'm a newbie) to attack the problem for the numbers atleast is:

```
$sequenceArr = [];
$string = '';
foreach(...){

   if(nextValue == prevValue+1){
      $sequenceArr[] = nextValue;
   }else{
      //form the string from the sequenceArr
      //if the preceeding string doesn't conform to the pattern anymore.
   }
}
```

The problem I think I will be facing above is if the inputs are not sorted.. I could "sort" them, but how about for strings with character values in them? I'm kinda lost, and I don't think I'm going anywhere with this solution.

***UPDATED FURTHER DESCRIPTION :**

This will just be a simple grouping algorithm, only the last number will indicate grouping,

AB-1-DF AB-2-DF and AB-3-DF will **NOT** be grouped to AB-1-DF - AB-3-DF. That simplifies the problem, also the 0 prefix doesn't matter, 001 and 002 can be grouped as 1-2.

The simple rule is basically this :

```
(character) - (number)
  ABC       -     1
```

A difference in character means an entirely different thing.

Comment: The problem is a bit under-defined. Is there stuffs like `ABC-1-DF,ABC-2-DF`? Do you have to deal with 0 prefix `001, 002`? What will happen when there are multiple numbers, e.g. `ABC-2-DF-1, ABC-3-DF-1, ABC-2-DF-2`?

Comment: yes.. there will be a lot of values , but basically the last numbers will only the one that's going to matter, so ABC-1-DF and ABC-2-DF are two separate things., if its ABC-DF-1 and ABC-DF-2 then they can be grouped, thanks for noticing that, about the prefix...no, I don't need to deal with 0 prefix

Comment: Split the last numbers from the string (e.g. `ABC4G54` to prefix `ABC4G` and number `54`), then put the pairs (prefix, number) in an array and sort them, then run your normal grouping algorithm. The splitting part can be done with regex or even a simple loop from the end of the string.

Comment: So how about array('N1', 'N02', 'N003'); ? Need to be 'N1 - N3'? or 'N1 - N003'? How about array('H1N1', 'H1N2', 'H2N3', 'H2N4'); ?

Comment: N1, N02, and N003 are considered different, I really appreciate the effort guys, thanks a lot. i'll update the description.

Comment: Do you mean the last number or the last digit ? This makes a difference. How will you group AA08, AA09, AA10, AA11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that ought to work if sequential items are next to one another. And you'd probably want to write your own `are_sequential` function:

```
$input = ["1","2","4","6","7","8"];

$len = count($input);
$result = [];

function are_sequential($a,$b){
  return $a + 1 == $b;
}

$i = 0;

while ($i < $len - 1){
  $first = $input[$i];
  $last = $input[$i];
  $i++;
  $sequenceLength = 1;
  while (are_sequential($last, $input[$i])){
    $last = $input[$i];
    $sequenceLength++;
    if ($i < $len - 1){
      $i++;
    }
  }
  if ($sequenceLength > 1){
    $result[] = $first . "-" . $last;
  } else {
    $result[] = $first;
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1-2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "6-8"
}
```

Comment: but how about for the strings containing character in it?

Comment: @muffin Think about how you would like to determine if two items are sequential. The function, `are_sequential` checks for that. How would you write it? (Or comment in words how you would check if two strings are sequential.)

Comment: oohhhhh i get it okay..so this is where the comparison takes place.. okay okay..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array increasingly using the standard string comparison predicate (alphabetical order).

Then compare the strings in pairs.

Isolate the string prefix (all characters but the last), and compare for equality.

If you accept numerical suffixes consisting of more than one digit, you will need to isolate the suffix, convert it to integer, and do the comparison on the remaining prefix. (Regular expressions can help you.)

Comment: I think in PHP you don't have to convert the string to an integer. For example, `("2" + 1 == "3")` would return a boolean `true`, and `("2" + 1 == "4")` would return a boolean `false`.